# Color tinted UIImages gets pixelated

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, cgcontext

I am having problem understanding the reason for the following method, to return images that are visibly pixelated. I have double checked the size of the image, and it is fine. What's more, without tinting it, the image edges are smooth, and lack pixelation.

The method for tinting image, based on IOS7 ImageView's tintColor property, works fine, however I would love to find out what is wrong with the following code, because it seems to work for everybody but me. Thanks!

```
- (UIImage *)imageTintedWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
if (color) {
    UIImage *img = self; // The method is a part of UIImage category, hence the "self"
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

    // get a reference to that context we created
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set the fill color
    [color setFill];

    // translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // set the blend mode to color burn, and the original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColorBurn);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

    // set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (color burn) a colored rectangle
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

    // generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
    UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return the color-burned image
    return coloredImg;
}

return self;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
```

to:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, NO, 0);
```

If your images will never have an transparency, change the `NO` to `YES`.

Comment: You were totally right! From the documentation: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() - This function is equivalent to calling the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions function with the opaque parameter set to NO and a scale factor of 1.0`. So the difference was "Scale factor". @rmaddy, could you explain what is the difference between scale factor 0 and 1?

Comment: A value of `0` means to determine whether a value of `1` or `2` should be used based on the device. A retina device will result in `2` being used while a non-retina device results in `1` being used.